# How to enable EIP 1559 transactions for EVM with frontier

Tags: evm

We are using [frontier](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier) https://github.com/paritytech/frontier for evm support in our substrate chain. EIP 1559 transactions is not enabled for our chain. How to enable EIP 1559 transactions?

Comment: The latest frontier support EIP 1559 transaction by default. Is your frontier version too old?

Comment: No we are using latest frontier https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar

Comment: What have you tried and what is the specific issue you are facing?

Comment: We are getting error EIP 1559 transaction not supported in metamask which checks this based on latest block containing baseFeePerGas which is not being returned. We have tried Ethereum::migrate_block_v0_to_v2 https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar/pull/629/files

Comment: It is working for our collator with --dev flag but not on live network.  https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar